# animating an update to the image property in mkannotationview

Tags: animation, uiimage, mkannotationview

i want to animate a change to the image used when displaying my mkannotationview.

i know that uiimageview allows for animating its image, but the mkannotationview is just a uiview with an image property.

i also realize that i could override the drawrect method of mkannnotationview, and fully customize the way the pin is displayed/updated, but i'd like to avoid that if possible, and simply animate the change of the image property.

is this possible, or is the drawrect approach my only option?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a timer could be used to change the image property on a set interval, or - you could subclass the annotation view and add your own uiimageview to the view hierarchy, and expose the uiimageview as a property.

Comment: thanks. i like the idea of the timer, thou i am not sure if the subclass+imageview property approach would work, since it is the MKMapView object that handles the display of the pin's image, and even if i override the image getter, i don't know if the uiimageview image animation functionality could be leveraged here. thoughts?

Comment: if you're overriding the annotation view -- then you have the capability to put any views you want on the view, and have total control over those views.  The map view itself is mostly concerned with the efficient vending of the views.